# How to completely remove phpMyAdmin without knowing its password?

Tags: apache2, password, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I know there are more questions about this problem "How to remove phpMyAdmin" but they did not work, because I lost my password! I lost my phpMyAdmin and MySQL password and username! I don't remember what they were and I just want to remove them because I deleted some of phpMyAdmin files suddenly + I don't use it, I use Cassandra and NEO4J and I don't use MySQL...

So, How can I remove them without having password and usename?

Comment: Removing software does not require you to provide a password or username for the software itself. You need your "sudo" password and to use your "sudo" user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge phpmyadmin
```

or as Rinzwind noted

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
```

this should (1) remove phpmyadmin and (2) remove its settings files and so on too.

Comment: Don't forget to run `sudo apt autoremove` and `sudo apt autoclean` afterwards to make sure it's all gone.